# double negation to statements contain several quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I would like to use double negation to equivalently re-express sentences contain several quantifiers.

And after reading related materials [Generalized quantifiers and relations](https://home.uni-leipzig.de/gkobele/courses/2020.SS/Semantics/posts/gqsrelations/), [Classical vs. modern squares of opposition, and beyond∗](https://www.philosophy.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.165900.1391710462!/menu/standard/file/2012%20Squares.pdf), I have the following association and don't know if it is correct.

E.g. Assuming there are many balls which have two sizes (small and large) and two colors (red and blue). This means that it only red balls or only blue balls or both have two sizes.

Is the sentence “At most 5 red balls are larger than exactly 3 blue balls” equals to “All red balls but at most 5 are not larger than exactly 3 blue balls. ”

I think the statement “At most 5 red balls are larger than exactly 3 blue balls” is True when

$$ (R \cap L \le 5) \& (B = 3 \& B \subseteq S)$$

where R denotes the red balls, L denotes large size, B denotes blue balls and S denotes small size. And when this statement is True, it means there are at most 5 large red balls and exactly 3 small blue balls.

I'm kind of confusing whether this sentence have an equal meaning as “All red balls but at most 5 are not larger than exactly 3 blue balls. ” or “All red balls but at most 5 are larger than not exactly 3 blue balls. ”

Comment: Note: It appears that the plenty of good contextual information (supplied by the OP) has been deleted from these comments.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the sentence “At most 5 red balls are larger than exactly 3 blue balls” equal to “All red balls but at most 5 are not larger than exactly 3 blue balls. ”

No. Assuming that the speaker isn't referring to three *particular* blue balls, then the former is equivalent to, for example, “It's not the case that at least 6 red balls are larger than fewer or more than 3 blue balls”, which can be symbolised as

$$\lnot\,∀x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\: ∃p\: ∀i{\in}\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\ ∀y_1∀y_∀y_3\: ∀m,n{\in}\{1,2,3\}\: ∃q\: ∃j{\in}\{1,2,3\}\: ∀k{\in}\{1,2,3\}\\
(p\ne x_i\land Rp\land\bigg((m\ne n\to y_m\ne y_n) \to\\
\Big((q=y_j \land\lnot\big(Bq\land Lpq\big)) \lor \big(q\ne y_k \land Bq\land Lpq\big)\Big)\bigg)).$$

Comment: Oh, I see! It seems like an iteration process. So for my second statement, “It’s not case that all red balls are not have the same size as most blue balls” is right, is it?

Comment: @Lauren 1. You say that you constructed all these given sentences.  It's more fruitful to disambiguate them (think about rewriting them while preserving intended meaning) rather than keep trying to form even more contrived equivalences from them.  2. Please use my examples (incl. in the previous Question), thinking about the translation structure (not necessarily formalising the sentences), to answer your own question; reminder: translate in steps.

Comment: @Lauren To be clear, the point is that the original verbal sentence is ambiguous and thus poorly-crafted, and the main point of analysing it and making a best guess of the intended meaning is as a cautionary lesson in avoiding ambiguity in the first place, or at least, in learning to recognise ambiguity and potential ambiguity.